# C# How to create an Excel 5.0/95 file

Tags: c#, excel

I need to create (save) an Excel 5.0/95 file with C# (to be use by an old software), but I'm stuck in not finding the necessary library.

Till this point I always used "EPPlus" (for `.xlsx` format) and "Excellibrary" (`.xls` format Excel 97-2003), and couldn't find a way to change the format in any of these two to save the Excel in 5.0/95.

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: You cannot create an .xlsx file, they did not exist back in 1995.  Finding a library that can still do this is tough shopping.  Excel itself can do it, use WorkBook.SaveAs() and set the 2nd format argument to xlExcel5.

Comment: Thank you, using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and `WorkBook.SaveAs()` I manage to save the file as Excel 5.0.